# Alternative to scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I was doing an agglomerative hierarchical clustering experiment in Python 3 and I found `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree()` is not returning the requested number of clusters for some input linkage matrices. So, by now I know there is a bug in the [cut_tree()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree.html) function (as described [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8063)).

However, I need to be able to get a flat clustering with an assignment of `k` different labels to my datapoints. Do you know the algorithm to get a flat clustering with `k` labels from an arbitrary input linkage matrix `Z`? My question boils down to: how can I compute what `cut_tree()` is computing from scratch with no bugs?

You can test your code with [this dataset](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2c18c87b83ddf610a9ee2396582892b620171021225708/f49c13).

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, is_valid_linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

## Load dataset
X = np.load("dataset.npy")

## Hierarchical clustering
dists = pdist(X)
Z = linkage(dists, method='centroid', metric='euclidean')

print(is_valid_linkage(Z))

## Now let's say we want the flat cluster assignement with 10 clusters.
#  If cut_tree() was working we would do
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import cut_tree
cut = cut_tree(Z, 10)
```

*Sidenote:* An alternative approach could maybe be using [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/)'s `cutree()` as a substitute for scipy's `cut_tree()`, but I never used it. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to obtain `k` flat clusters is to use `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster` with `criterion='maxclust'`:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
clust = fcluster(Z, k, criterion='maxclust')
```