# How to make fcluster to return the same output as cut_tree?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

There are a couple of related questions to this, the most relevant is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869640/alternative-to-scipy-cluster-hierarchy-cut-tree) I think.

Let's say I have a dataset like this (highly simplified for demonstration purposes):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.spatial import distance
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

val = np.array([[0.20288834,   0.80406494,   4.59921579,  14.28184739],
                [0.22477082,   1.43444223,   6.87992605,  12.90299896],
                [0.22811485,   0.74509454,   3.85198421,  19.22564266],
                [0.20374529,   0.73680174,   3.63178517,  17.82544951],
                [0.22722696,   0.86113728,   3.00832186,  16.62306058],
                [0.25577882,   0.85671779,   3.70655719,  17.49690061],
                [0.23018219,   0.68039151,   2.50815837,  15.09039053],
                [0.21638751,   1.12455083,   3.56246872,  18.82866991],
                [0.26600895,   1.09415595,   2.85300018,  17.93139433],
                [0.22369445,   0.73689845,   3.24919113,  18.60914745]])

df = pd.DataFrame(val, columns=["C{}".format(i) for i in range(val.shape[1])])

         C0        C1        C2         C3
0  0.202888  0.804065  4.599216  14.281847
1  0.224771  1.434442  6.879926  12.902999
2  0.228115  0.745095  3.851984  19.225643
3  0.203745  0.736802  3.631785  17.825450
4  0.227227  0.861137  3.008322  16.623061
5  0.255779  0.856718  3.706557  17.496901
6  0.230182  0.680392  2.508158  15.090391
7  0.216388  1.124551  3.562469  18.828670
8  0.266009  1.094156  2.853000  17.931394
9  0.223694  0.736898  3.249191  18.609147
```

I want to cluster the columns of this dataframe and thereby also specify the number of clusters I obtain. Typically, this can be achieved by using the [cut_tree function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree.html).

However, currently, `cut_tree` [is broken](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8063) and therefore I looked for alternatives which led me to the link at the beginning of this post where it is suggested to use [fcluster](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html) as alternative.

Problem is that I don't see how to specify an exact number of clusters but only a maximum number using the `maxclust` argument.

So for my simple example from above I can do:

```
# number of target cluster
n_clusters = range(1, 5)

for n_clust in n_clusters:
    Z = hierarchy.linkage(distance.pdist(df.T.values), method='average', metric='euclidean')

    print("--------\nValues from flcuster:\n{}".format(hierarchy.fcluster(Z, n_clust, criterion='maxclust')))
    print("\nValues from cut_tree:\n{}".format(hierarchy.cut_tree(Z, n_clust).T))
```

which prints

```
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 1]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 0 0 0]]
--------
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 2]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 0 0 1]]
--------
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 2]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 0 1 2]]
--------
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 2]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 1 2 3]]
```

As one can see, `fcluster` returns 2 distinct clusters at maximum while `cut_tree` returns the desired number.

Is there a way to get the same output for `fcluster` for the time until the bug in `cut_tree` is fixed? If not, is there any other good alternative for this in another package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how to get the right number of clusters out of `fcluster` here.

As an alternative, scikit-learn has [`AgglomerativeClustering`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html):

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

# number of target cluster
n_clusters = range(1, 5)

for n_clust in n_clusters:
    Z = hierarchy.linkage(distance.pdist(df.T.values), method='average', metric='euclidean')

    print("--------\nValues from flcuster:\n{}".format(hierarchy.fcluster(Z, n_clust, criterion='maxclust')))
    print("\nValues from cut_tree:\n{}".format(hierarchy.cut_tree(Z, n_clust).T))

    print("\nValues from AgglomerativeClustering:\n{}".format(AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n_clust, affinity='euclidean', linkage='average').fit(df.T.values).labels_))
```

which returns the right number of clusters for the provided dataset (although in different order):

```
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 1]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 0 0 0]]

Values from AgglomerativeClustering:
[0 0 0 0]
--------
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 2]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 0 0 1]]

Values from AgglomerativeClustering:
[0 0 0 1]
--------
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 2]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 0 1 2]]

Values from AgglomerativeClustering:
[0 0 2 1]
--------
Values from flcuster:
[1 1 1 2]

Values from cut_tree:
[[0 1 2 3]]

Values from AgglomerativeClustering:
[3 1 2 0]
```